# Paying directly to Alipay

Tags: meaning-in-context

Because of certain reason, I can't pay the seller through the marketplace platform. Is it appropriate to use:

我可以直接转你们的支付宝上吗？

to ask to pay them directly to their Alipay account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 我可以直接转你们的支付宝上吗

You missed a preposition

我可以直接[转]你们的支付宝上吗? = Can I directly [transfer] your AliPay? (X)

我可以直接[转**到**]你们的支付宝上吗? = Can I directly [transfer **to**] your AliPay? (O)

我可以直接[转**入**]你们的支付宝上吗? = Can I directly [transfer **into**] your AliPay? (O)

Comment: I think it is OK. Such as 我可以转你银行吗？ with the context that we are doing a transaction. Also, one can say 可以转支付宝吗? if the context has that I should transfer the money to you, and 支付宝, like Zelle and Venmo, is direct by default.

Comment: I think it would be acceptable if "上" is removed.